# Powershell get-content command

Tags: powershell

I am trying to return only key from the text file having below content

```
{
    "expires":  "2018-02-24T19:40:35.000Z",
    "id":  "xtysdasdagsweasdasvfdsgsdfcxaxasdasrgdascasdasdasxacasdgshgsfdfgasdasdsaedasdasdasfeasdfasdasdasd==",
    "testvalue1":  "test_tenant"
}
```

above mentioned "id" is token which keep getting change everyday.
my final out put should only content id value without "" something like below.

```
xtysdasdagsweasdasvfdsgsdfcxaxasdasrgdascasdasdasxacasdgshgsfdfgasdasdsaedasdasdasfeasdfasdasdasd==
```

I have tried with '''get-content -path c:..\filname.txt | select-string "id"''' but it does not return only key as mentioned above.

it returns full line

```
"id":  "xtysdasdagsweasdasvfdsgsdfcxaxasdasrgdascasdasdasxacasdgshgsfdfgasdasdsaedasdasdasfeasdfasdasdasd==",
```

How to select only specific output I am referring?

Comment: PLEASE fix your code/data formatting. there is a how-to link on the page you used to create your Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-Content` reads the file off disk, but you need to convert the resulting JSON string to an object you can interact with to get the `id` value:

```
# Read from disk and convert from JSON
$data = Get-Content -Path C:\path\to\filname.txt |ConvertFrom-Json

# Now we can dereference the `id` property value alone
$data.id
```

Comment: Thanks Jessen, I am trying to define it as a variable and then in header I am trying to define it again to use under invoke-resthost